# while changing the length in Data Conversion in SSIS

Tags: ssis

i am using Data Convesion in SSIS. I specifieed properties but i can't change length. Please help me.
It's 0 by default when i run it it gives me error for possibity to loose data and do not convert data .

I am converting DT_STR to Database time

Please help me

Thanking you

Comment: right click on the data conversion transformation and select advanced editor then input/output column properties to make the changes

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
Yes i did the same  but its disabled somewhere or i don't know what but i can't change the length.

Comment: if it is date time then it would not have length right? if there is a data issue then use derived column to create a date time field

Answer (score 0):

The Data Conversion transformation will not change the length of a column for you automatically. Best practice would be to convert the length of the column when pulling from your source, either by specifying it with a SQL query or specifying it through an underlying view.

However, if you can't supply the correct length in your data source the next best option would be to use a [Derived Column](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/andy_leonard/archive/2009/02/04/ssis-expression-language-and-the-derived-column-transformation.aspx) transformation. With a Derived Column transformation you'll be able to specify a certain number of characters with the LEFT() function, if that's what you want.

Comment: Hi,   
      Thank you for your reply. I changed the size while sending input to the data conversion. I made it 5000 for database timestamp. But still its not working.

Please help me.

Thank you